# How to do good custom routing with CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-1.3

I am planning to rewrite my site into CakePHP and after having spent a full week on learning it, I am still not sure how to do good custom routing in CakePHP.

This is what I want:

- Keep the current url structure in www.domain.tld/en/dragons.html, or use a www.domain.tld/en/dragons, but not www.domain.tld/en/nodes/dragons.html. And also be able to use controllers on a similar path structure.

There are about 100 static pages on the entire site. I have read into multi-language routing and I think I can do it. I can also make /en/* or /en/:slug route via a PagesControler or a self-written NodesController.

My problem is that I would like to be able to mix and match url's with and without controllers, so actually what I want is that it checks if a :slug is part of the slug-list, there should still be the option to use that url with a controller.

I have created routes for both /en/contact and /en/:slugid, but it seems all queries were routed to my NodesController, even while I explicitly said that /en/contact should be routed to the ContactsController.

How can I instruct Cakephp to keep my current dictorary structure? I read the routes part of the Cakephp book, but it was extremely short and made me a little unsure about the possibility of such routing. If necessary, I'll just write a php-code that prints all routes for all slugs, so I can still write controller-routes with a similar path structure.

Comment: Post the routes you have currently.

Comment: are you using a database for your website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a file exists in webroot (ie. `app/webroot/static.html`), the .htaccess file will tell Apache to serve that file before loading the CakePHP framework for requests to `www.example.com/static.html`.

Cake loads routes in a top-down order and will use the first matching route to handle a request. In your case, `/en/contact` should be above `/en/:slugid`, else the slugid rule will always win.

If CakePHP's routing does not accomplish what you are after, you can always implement a custom route class ([book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1634/Custom-Route-classes) / [example](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp)).